# Specifying concrete type of ActionResult

Tags: c#, mvc, asp.net-mvc

There are loads of types implementing ActionResult like ViewResult, PartialViewResult, JsonResult, RedirectResult and so on. I have seen two approaches when creating action methods, either always use ActionResult or specify the concrete type which is returned by the action (if possible). What advantage does specifying concrete type ActionResult has? All I can think of currently is that having concrete type would make unit testing the controllers easier (if you actually write unit tests for controllers).

Comment: Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/a/4743782/4714502

Answer (score 2):

> What is the advantage of specifying a concrete type of ActionResult?

It will enforce that only that type may be returned. If you specify `JsonResult`, you can be sure `ViewResult` is not returned. This may be useful if you explicitly want to create a JSON interface, and you don't want others to add a view.

> having concrete type would make unit testing the controllers easier

Not really. It would save you one assertion and a cast in your unit test. This is not a good reason to not return a polymorphic type.

[The docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult(v=vs.118).aspx) explain the rationale for returning `ActionResult`

> It is helpful to set the return type to ActionResult because in more complicated action methods, you may need to return different types of results for different scenarios. For example, the registration action method from the default MVC template, redirects the users if registration is successful, but displays the error messages if registration fails.